# Windows Script Host - Unable to get StdOut from console

Tags: java, excel, vba, stdout, wsh

I need a hand with a specific doubt regarding VBA, Excel and WSH.
I have a excel that I want to use to run a jar. This jar takes up to 4 seconds to return a anser using System.out.println.

I created a script in VBA in excel to run this jar and to collect the results via StdOut.ReadAll, but the problem is that everytime I run it I don't get nothing as result... I'm executing the java and it is returning 1000, when I execute the vba it seems nothing happens.

This is my VBA code:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Sub Test()
Dim prog As Object
Dim Exec As Object
Dim A As String
Set prog = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set Exec = prog.Exec("java -jar JExcel.jar " & Range("a2").Value) <- Im passing an argument here
    While Exec.Status = WshRunning
        Range("b2") = "Running"
        Sleep (100)
    Wend
Range("b2").Value = Exec.StdOut.ReadAll
End Sub
```

I read a lot of material in here and other places but got no lucky.

Does anyone knows what might be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353522/real-time-console-output-from-wscript-shell-exec) offer any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real time console output from WScript.Shell Exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353522/real-time-console-output-from-wscript-shell-exec)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both Java and your `.jar` file are not located in Excel's default save path (which you can check with VBA property `Application.DefaultFilePath`), you need to specify a path or two.

I'm actually unfamiliar with Java, but if your `PATH` evnironment variable (VBA: `Environ("Path")`) includes the path for the Java executable then that part should be fine, but I'd imagine you still have to specify the path for the `.jar`.

Also, there's a simpler way to call `Shell`:

```
Dim RetVal
RetVal = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\CALC.EXE", 1)    ' Run Calculator.
```

---

### Shell Function

Runs an executable program and returns a `Variant (Double)` representing the program's `Task ID` if successful, otherwise it returns zero.

**Syntax**

**`Shell( pathname [, windowstyle ] )`**

<sub>The Shell function syntax has these named arguments:</sub>

- **pathname** (*Required*; `Variant (String)`) Name of the program to execute and any required arguments or command-line switches; **may include directory or folder and drive**.
- **windowstyle**  (*Optional*; `Variant (Integer)`) corresponding to the style of the window in which the program is to be run. If `windowstyle` is omitted, the program is started minimized with focus.

The `windowstyle` named argument has these values:

```
Constant          Value Description
vbHide              0   Window is hidden and focus is passed to the hidden window.
vbNormalFocus       1   Window has focus and is restored to its original size and position.
vbMinimizedFocus    2   Window is displayed as an icon with focus.
vbMaximizedFocus    3   Window is maximized with focus.
vbNormalNoFocus     4   Window is restored to its most recent size and position. 
                        The currently active window remains active.
vbMinimizedNoFocus  6   Window is displayed as an icon. 
                        The currently active window remains active.
```

**Remarks**

If the *`Shell`* function successfully executes the named file, it returns the *Task ID* of the started program. The *Task ID* is a unique number that identifies the running program. If the `Shell` function can't start the named program, an error occurs.

**Note**

By default, the `Shell` function runs other programs asynchronously. This means that a program started with `Shell` might not finish executing before the statements following the `Shell` function are executed.

<sub>([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/shell-function))</sub>