VBA shell command focus control
I have 2 solutions for running a shell command :-

in the first my command runs in minimized mode but returned result is not the full message return I require

result = Shell(Command, vbMinimizedNoFocus)    

in the 2nd the command runs and I received the required return message BUT the shell window runs in NormalFocus mode
Dim oShell As Object
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'run command
Dim oExec As Object
Dim oOutput As Object
Set oExec = oShell.Exec(Command)
Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut
   
'handle the results as they are written to and read from the StdOut object

Dim sLine As String
While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
    sLine = oOutput.ReadLine
    If sLine <> "" Then oResult = oResult & sLine
Wend

What do I need to do to get the 2nd routine to run in vbMinimizedNoFocus mode ?
Tried adding the command within the exec line
eg
Set oExec = oShell.Exec(Command,vbMinimizedNoFocus)

but just causes a compilation error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353522/real-time-console-output-from-wscript-shell-exec
